# How to change "Add to cart" button color in opencart 2.1.0.1?

Tags: css, opencart2.x

I wants to change "Add to cart" button colour from blue to black completely

Actually I got success in changing colour but when click on Button, it displaying

its existing "blue" colour as "loading" text. I tried this change from

catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css.

Thanks

Comment: What is the class of the button? Have you try setting :active state of the button to your desired color ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find what default class is there on all button's. Suppose that class is `.button` so you can apply css on this class with all conditions of hover, active etc.

```
.button, .button:hover, .button:focus, .button:active, .button.active{
  color:#000;
}
```

This way you can handle this button completely for all these condition or may be some more condition if i have missed anyone.

> Right now the condition for your problem is `:focus` but handling all the situation will reduces chances for error in future.